# How do I get chrome to use a time value in an html form?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor, momentjs

I am using momentjs LT(local time) and L(local Date) in a meteor app to set the current time and date value in an html form.  It is working in Firefox, but in chrome i am getting --:-- -.  Does chrome not support type="time" with a value, or am i setting the time incorrectly?

```
HTML
    <input type="time" name="fTime" value={{time}}>
    <input type="date" name="fDate" value={{date}}>


JS
Template.registerHelper('date', function(input) {
  return moment().format('L');
});

Template.registerHelper('time', function(input) {
  return moment().format('LT');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome expects a 24-hour clock, as in `value="13:34"` or the like. It also wants a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, like 2015-03-08. So change your helpers to accommodate:

```
Template.registerHelper('date', function(input) {
  return moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
});

Template.registerHelper('time', function(input) {
  return moment().format('H:mm');
});
```

See example: http://meteorpad.com/pad/XiZBySYHfEydaaZbb/Input%20date%20and%20time%20test (works for me in Chrome in the U.S. locale).

Note that per [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=time%20input), support for these input types is spotty—no versions of Safari or Internet Explorer.

Comment: So that definitely worked chrome, but now i have military time and date inverted in the other browsers.  It seems to be working in ie also, havent tested safari yet.

Comment: I don’t think this is a standardized input type just yet. You’re probably better off using a date/time widget for now.